# Gradle: Prevent execution of tasks defined in allProjects for root project

Tags: gradle, build, build-process

I have a flat multi-project configuration like this:

```
projA
projB
projC
build_scripts
```

`build_scripts` contains `build.gradle`

`build.gradle` looks like this:

```
allprojects {
    ...
    task gitPull(type: Exec) {
        description 'Pulls git.'
        commandLine "git", "pull"
    }
}
project(':projA') {
...
}
project(':projB') {
...
}
project(':projC') {
...
}
```

When I run `gradle gitPull` from the `build_scripts` directory then I want
gradle to  execute `git pull` in directories of `projA`, `projB` and `projC` (and nowhere else).

However, since gralde treats `build_scripts` as the root project, it executes `git pull` there as well - which fails because it is not a git repository (or even if it is, I would not want to execute `git pull` on it while building the project)

In general, I don't want the `build_scripts` folder i.e. the root project to participate in any build related activity. 
How do I exclude the root project from been acted upon by tasks specified in `allProjects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Gradle turorials](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html):

In this example you can see how `configure` filters out the project `tropicalFish` from executing the task `hello`.

> Example 56.8. Adding custom behaviour to some projects (filtered by
>   project name)

```
   ....
```

> Note: The code for this example can be found at
>   samples/userguide/multiproject/addTropical/water in the ‘-all’
>   distribution of Gradle.

Settings.gradle

```
include 'bluewhale', 'krill','tropicalFish'
```

build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    task hello << {task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
}
subprojects {
    hello << {println "- I depend on water"}
}
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'tropicalFish'}) {
    hello << {println '- I love to spend time in the arctic waters.'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not have to use the `configure()`. All I did was add a `subprojects {}` entry and move the task from `allprojects{}` to `subprojects{}`